# How to extend a logical volume which has snapshot on it

Tags: storage, openstack, lvm

I have a lv(logical volume) which is a original source of another snapshot. And I wanna extend the lv with command 'lvextend' and the first try failed with error:

```
Snapshot origin volumes can be resized only while inactive
```

So I tried the second way with a command sequence.

```
1. unmount [mount_path]
2. deactive the device with command(lvchange -an [device_path])
3. lvextend [device_path]
```

then I get the error:

```
LV [device_namr] has open snapshot [snapshot_name]: not deactivating
```

What should I do, how can I extend a lv with snapshot exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must deactivate your snapshot too, with command:

```
lvchange -an [snapshot_path]
```

and when both of volume and snapshot are inactive, you can extend your volume.

Comment: example: `lvchange -an /dev/vg0/snap-tmp-vm04.debian-disk`

Comment: But then how do I extend the volume that's mapped to `/`... Surely I can't just deactivate it

Comment: @Hubro, you need to boot with another live OS to make that happen. for example, make a flash drive bootable with an Ubuntu desktop version and boot with that live OS, and then you can make any changes you want on the `/` disk

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deactivate the volume that is mounted to `/` you can resize it to occupy the empty space on your disk while the volume is mounted mounted

1. To deactivate your snapshot do
   `lvchange -an /path/to/snapshot`
2. To extend the voulume that's mapped to `/` use the `--resizefs` option of `lvextend`

Comment: This also deactivates the origin, hence it tries to deactivate / and fails